# How to introduce the attributes of an object in python by calling a method in __init__ method?

Tags: python, oop

As a simple example, let's assume that we want to create a lot of `Earthquake` instances, having name, origin time, and hypocenter coordinate attributes coming from other sources encoded as strings (`"Nepal 25-4-2015T11:56:26 28.14 84.71 15.0"`).

```
class Earthquake(object):
    def __init__(self, strline):
        ....
```

So, what we must do is:

1. parse the string to receive name, date, time, latitude, longitude and depth.
2. instantiate `Earthquake` by passing those values to initialization call `__init__`.

Imagine the first part is done by a simple function:

```
import datetime as dt

def myfunc(strline):
    items = line.split()
    name = items[0]
    otime = dt.datetime.strptime(items[1], "%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S")
    lat, lon, depth = map(float, items[2:])
```

Now I want to use the class `class Earthquake` to create `Earthquake` objects in a way that each object has attributes `Earthquake.name`, `Earthquake.otime`, `Earthquake.lat`, `Earthquake.lon` and `Earthquake.depth`.

How can I call `myfunc` method in `__init__` method in a class to initialize an object with above attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do that completely the other way around. Parsing that string is clearly part of what an `Earthquake` object should do, so provide it as an alternate constructor using a *class method*:

```
class Earthquake(object):

    def __init__(self, name, otime, lat, lon, depth):
        self.name = name
        self.otime = otime
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
        self.depth = depth

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, strline):
        items = line.split()
        name = items[0]
        otime = dt.datetime.strptime(items[1], "%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S")
        lat, lon, depth = map(float, items[2:])
        return cls(name, otime, lat, lon, depth)
```

Now you call e.g.:

```
quake = Earthquake.from_string("Nepal 25-4-2015T11:56:26 28.14 84.71 15.0")
```

---

Or, if you want the function to remain standalone, add a `return` to it:

```
def myfunc(strline):
    ...
    return name, otime, lat, lon, depth
```

and make the class method call it:

```
class Earthquake(object):

    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, strline):
        return cls(*myfunc(strline))
```

*(if this syntax is unfamiliar, see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761))*

Answer (score 3):

One of the things you could do is call Earthquake with the string as a parameter and on `__init__` you call the parsing function.

```
import datetime as dt

class Earthquake(object):
    def __init__(self, strline):
        self.parse_data(strline)

    def parse_data(self, strline):
        items = line.split()
        self.name = items[0]
        self.otime = dt.datetime.strptime(items[1], "%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S")
        self.lat, self.lon, self.depth = map(float, items[2:])
```

Comment: Some linters will complain that you're setting instance attributes outside of `__init__`. This also makes it slightly more difficult to test the class, as there's no way to initialise it without formatting the input data into the string required.